# How to run a standalone jar from spark.

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am very new to spark, just learning so please bear with me if I talk like a novice.

I have a regular java jar which is self contained,

The function of this jar is to listen to a queue and process some messages. Now the requirement is to read from the queue in a distributed fashion so I have a spark master and three slaves managed by Yarn. When I ./spark-submit this jar file on the standalone master all works fine. When I switch to a cluster mode by setting Yarn as master in the commandline I get lots of errors of file not found at HDFS. 
I read up on stack and saw that I have to mention SparkContext but however I see no use of it in my case.

There is questions here:

Do I still have to use the

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-cluster").setAppName("TibcoMessageConsumer");
        SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf);
```

I dont see any usage of `sparkContext` in my case.

Comment: You can't run a jar using `spark-submit` without a `SparkContext` in it.

Comment: I successfully did that on a single node!! What use would be the spark context here? Please bear with me if I dont make sense.

Comment: spark-submit worked without a spark context? Thanks, I didn't know that. I'll start reading what I can find regarding that.

Comment: Yes it did buddy, now I suspect the distribution of jars. So I am copying the files to HDFS as user4324225 has mentioned below and will check back with results.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Yarn, copy the jar to hdfs  and then you can reference that in spark-submit.  If you want to use a local file system, you have to copy that jar in all the worker nodes [not recommended]

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--class <main-class> \
--master <master-url> \
--deploy-mode cluster \
 myapp-jar
```

You can look at this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) for more details